# How do I combine two array into cohesive objects using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two arrays

```
var employeeIds = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};

var employeeNames = new [] {"Sarah", "Connor", "Julia", "Igor" };
```

I need to `Zip` them  so I can combine the above to array such that the `employeeId` at index `n` is combined with `employeeName` at index `n`. So I can get anonymous objects like the following

```
combinedArrays.Select(items => new {Id = items.Item0, Name = items.Item1 });
```

How do I do that in Linq? If I could get `Index` in Linq, that would've done it but IEnumerable is not an ordered collection so there is no indexes.

Answer (score 6):

You mentioned `Zip` - why not use that?

```
employeeNames.Zip(employeeIds, (name, id) => new { Id = id, Name = name });
```

MSDN for Enumerable.Zip: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, because you mentioned it you can access the index with the Select method if needed:

```
var employeeNames = new [] {"Sarah", "Connor", "Julia", "Igor" };
var indices = employeeNames.Select( (name, index) => index );
```

Comment: Damnit, there is a Zip in Linq to Enumerables?

Comment: @fahadash there sure is

Comment: @fahadash also because you mentioned it you can access the index with Select if  needed. i edited my answer to show